# How do you find the max in a particular cell across all sheets and return a different cell?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have been able to return the max value of F1 from all sheets by using this formula located in cell G13:

```
G13=MAX(ABC:XYZ!F1)
```

Now I also want to return the value of A5 from the sheet where the MAX was found in G13.

How do I write the formula for that?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `non-volatile` alternative, which references the maximum value you have already calculated in cell `G13`:

`=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,ABC:XYZ!A5)&"</b></a>","//b"),MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(G13,ABC:XYZ!F1),0))`

Comment: I am getting #REF returned in this case. 

The Max is calculated in G13 and is reflected in F1 of one of the sheets.

Comment: I like this one better.  The only drawback would be if the number of digits on all the pages with the a's and b's exceeded 255 characters.

Comment: @ScottCraner Absolutely, this is not a viable solution if the referened cells in question contain strings of large length.

Comment: The Longest name of a sheet is 5 letters.

Comment: @PaulDavis The length of the sheet names is not an issue here.

Comment: Yes, they're less than 9 digits each. They're dollar values and could go above 9... but shouldn't on average.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah, no! Are you sure it's not 32,767 characters?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Comment: I stand corrected. @JosWoolley

Comment: I have found the reason... I hadn't listed some of the sheet names... I am just going to list them now and see if this works.

Comment: @PaulDavis Using the formula I posted, if you go into the formula bar and highlight just the portion `MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(G13,ABC:XYZ!F1),0)` and then press F9, what result do you get?

Comment: @PaulDavis Re "I hadn't listed some of the sheet names...", I assume you intended that comment for Scott's post? My solution does not require a list of sheet names to be created.

Comment: Sorry Jos, I did put that comment in the wrong place. I am trying your way now. I highlighted that area you recommended and I ended up with 26 as the result.

Comment: Thanks. Can you put this formula into a cell somewhere and tell me what it returns: `=ROWS(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,ABC:XYZ!A5)&"</b></a>","//b"))`

Comment: Ah, wait. Some of the sheets have a blank in cell A5?

Comment: Apologies Jos, I am not quite sure what you're expecting me to do with that formula. If I put it in and do the F9 technique, it comes up #NAME.

Comment: YES! That was it... It was a forgotten A5!!! Thank you! Genius!

Comment: Glad we finally got there! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Create a named range that includes all the sheet names.

[image]

Then using INDEX/MATCH and INDIRECT inside MAX and SUMIFS we get:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(Sheets)&"'!A5"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(Sheets)&"'!f1")),SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(Sheets)&"'!F1"),"<>"),0))
```

Depending on one's version one may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

The `HERE` is coming from `Sheet2!A5` where `Sheet2!F1` has `1000` in it.  All other sheets have `1` in `F1`

Comment: I gave this a try with:
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(A2:A25)&"'!A5"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(A2:A25)&"'!f1")),SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(A2:A25)&"'!F1"),"<>"),0))

But I return #NA

Comment: A2:A25 contains the names of all the sheets.

Comment: Did you try with Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  What version are you using?  It works just fine for me in O365

Comment: Oh, OK, I tried ctrl+shift+enter and I get an answer, but it is the incorrect answer. It has just returned the first sheet.

Comment: Im not sure why it does not work for you, it works with my test.  As does Jos' answer.

Comment: Your formula returned an answer though. But just not the expected answer. Where Jos answer is returning #REF. I am using 2019.

Comment: I do not have access to 2019 to test, so I am not sure how to adjust to work with 2019.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I did go with Jos' method below and it has worked once I found out I had left some data out of old sheets. Thank you.

Comment: I would have chosen that one too.  Glad you found an answer that worked.